# converting xml to html table cannot get it right

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

New to xslt so go easy ,I am been trying to convert an xml to html via xslt and I cannot seem to get it right.

Headers and rows should not be hardcoded and should be as generic as possible.

Wanted result:

> [image: Employees]

Xml Used that I have no control over

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Generated>
      <Employees>
        <Employee name="Joe Bloggs">
          <Sales>
            <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="333" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="a" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="b" />
          </Sales>
        </Employee>
        <Employee name="Mark Bloggs">
          <Sales>
            <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="334" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="c" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="d" />
          </Sales>
        </Employee>
      </Employees>
    </Generated>
```

XSLT My Attempt

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html" version="4" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
      <!-- main body -->
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <body>
            <h3>Employees</h3>
            <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="blue">
                <!--Header only so select first row to get headers-->
                <xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)[1]/Sales/Sale">
                  <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                  </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </tr>
              <!--Get all the other rows-->
              <xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)/Sales/Sale">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
              </table>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Wrong outcome

> [image]

Any suggestion how to fix this and get my wanted result as per image above

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
          <xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)/Sales/Sale">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
          <xsl:for-each select="Generated/Employees/Employee">
            <tr>
             <xsl:for-each select="Sales/Sale">
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
              </td>
             </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: ,wow that worked 99%.what I miss is how do I get the name.Do I need another nested foreach?and how?

Comment: @developer9969 No, you do not need an additional `for-each` - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [Martin Honnen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27756569/1987598) (please accept his answer).

> what I miss is how do I get the name.Do I need another nested foreach?and how?

No need for an additional `for-each`. Introduce another `td` at the beginning of the first row and call it "Name". Then, inside the `for-each` for each `Employee` element, output a `td` element that contains the value of `@name`.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"></xsl:output>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <h3>Employees</h3>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="blue">
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)[1]/Sales/Sale">
                     <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@key"></xsl:value-of>
                     </th>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="Generated/Employees/Employee">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
                     </td>
                     <xsl:for-each select="Sales/Sale">
                        <td>
                           <xsl:value-of select="@value"></xsl:value-of>
                        </td>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h3>Employees</h3>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="blue">
            <td>Name</td>
            <th>Sale-Id</th>
            <th>Sale-Field1</th>
            <th>Sale-Field2</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
            <td>333</td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Mark Bloggs</td>
            <td>334</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>d</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered HTML**

> [image]